# Java App to .EXE - Derby DB

Tags: java, distribution, derby, launch4j

I have a Java Application (allows people to enter in sales). It is connected to a Derby Database. The app was developed using NetBeans IDE. I need to convert this app to a .exe for distribution. Normally I would use Launch4j for this, but since the app is linked to the Derby DB will it still work? If not is there another way to turn the app into a .exe file?

Comment: You mean, will it be able to still connect to the Derby server when it is distributed? Or will it work the same way after the "conversion" to .exe ?

Comment: Yes. If I were to convert the jar to an exe like I would for a regular app. Would this one still be able to connect to the Derby DB, or would I need to find a different type of conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application will work the same way as it did before. You should note that "conversion" to .exe is not really a conversion, it just provides a convenient way of executing the java program in Windows (much like a run-able JAR file).

In case you run a Derby server, it will connect to that server the same way as before. However if you are running Derby in embedded mode, you should make sure the database files will be located at correct path in the filesystem (you shouldn't archive the Derby files in your .exe)